# C++ invoking callback with C calling conventions

Tags: c++, c, callback, header, calling-convention

I have a library with a C-compatible header.
This library is implemented 100% in C++.
Despite this, it is important that the calling conventions are all C, because the library functions will be called from both C and C++ code.

```c
// HEADER (C/C++)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef void(*my_callback)(int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

```cpp
// SOURCE (C++)
void foo(my_callback callback) {
    callback(2);
}
```

How do I ensure that `my_callback` will always be invoked with C calling conventions? Is it enough that the `typedef` is inside an `extern "C"` block?

Comment: The function you supply as an argument of `foo()` must also be specified as `extern "C"` in C++, accept an argument of type `int`, and return `void`.

Comment: @Peter `int` in C++ as an extern? Could you please write what you mean? I am interested in this question too

Comment: The function you passed to `foo()` must be defined in C++ as something like `extern "C" void your_funky_callback(int x) {}`.

Comment: @Peter that's right, but how do I ensure that I always invoke `callback` inside `foo()` with C calling conventions, despite being in C++ code?

Comment: Exactly as you have done it - `void foo(my_callback callback) {callback(2);}`.      If you want to do it without your typedef of `my_callback` it is `void foo(extern "C" void (*callback)(int)) {callback(2);}`.   Nothing more needed in the body of the function if the type of `callback` is specified correctly.